# Using custom WP-API endpoints with the included Backbone JS client library

Tags: wp-api

So I have created a custom endpoint using [WP-API plugin](http://v2.wp-api.org/). When testing with Postman, the endpoint works as expected.

The problem is that when I try to access the custom enpoint using the built in [Backbone JS client](https://github.com/WP-API/client-js), I cannot see my new endpoints in the wp.api.models object.

I have been digging and I think I have to send initialise it with a different schema or something, but have aboslutely no idea how to and can't find any info on how to extend wp.api.models so I can access my custom methods.

**Example plugin code:**

```
function my_awesome_func( $data ) {
    return 'A STRING';
}

function initrest() {
    register_rest_route( 'wp/v2', '/score', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
    ));
} 

add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'initrest');
```

**Example template code:**

```
window.onload = function() {
    console.log(wp.api.models);
};
```

This ouputs a list of the common models for Post, Comment, Tags etc, but no sign of my 'scores' endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the wp api with your own route.

```
wp.api.init({'versionString' : 'custom-route/v1/',  'apiRoot': 'http://my-website.com/wp-json/'}).done(function()
{ 
  console.log(wp.api.models);
});
```

Whereas versionString and apiRoot need to be replaced with your own data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid custom endpoints don't make into the `wp.api.models` by design of the Backbone client. Have a look to [my question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/266890/rest-api-backbone-and-custom-endpoint) and the respective answers. They boil down to: "use a different client".

I use [node-wpapi](https://github.com/WP-API/node-wpapi).